# How do i get the Width of TextBox at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, textbox, width

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" PreviewKeyUp="TextBox_PreviewKeyUp"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "Some text inside Textbox";
            MessageBox.Show("TextBox1 Width = " + TextBox1.Width + " & TextBox1.ActualWidth = " + TextBox1.ActualWidth); // NaN & 10
        }
    }
}
```

How do I dynamically get the width of `TextBox`? `Width` and `ActualWidth` give me only the default compile time values, but I need the Width property after it has been compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Width` and `ActualWidth` do *not* give you the default compile time values.

`Width` is the *requested* size.

`ActualWidth` is the *rendered* size. 
From MSDN

> ActualWidth is a calculated value, and there can be multiple or incremental reported changes to the value because of operations by the layout system. If you get the value while layout is still iterating, the layout system might still be calculating the required measure of space for child objects, constraints by the parent object, and so on.

In your case, if you want the actual size of the item, use `ActualWidth`.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, I'm showing you how to make your specific method work, by using a BeginInvoke,to give the ActualWidth a chance to be calculated:

```
private void TextBox1_PreviewKeyUp_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        TextBox1.Text = "Some other text";
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)new Action(() =>
            MessageBox.Show("TextBox1 Width = " + TextBox1.Width + " & TextBox1.ActualWidth = " + TextBox1.ActualWidth)),
          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input);
}
```

Comment: I get ActualWidth = 10, which is compiletime value. I need the Width after the TextBox has been filled with Text and extended wider than default compiletime value of 10. ActualWidth is a calculated value in COMPILE TIME. LOOK AT MY EXAMPLE.

Comment: can't you just add the ActualWidth + the TextBox.Text.Length?

Comment: I ran your demo, without the `TextBox.Text = ...` and ActualWidth keeps changing on every key I click, just as expected.... Use `Debug.Print` instead of a messageBox and you can see it in the Output Window. The reason you don't see it is, just like I quoted, ActualWidth is a calculated field, you need to give it a chance, after you change the Text property, for it to be calculated.

Comment: Length of characters is not width of textbox. ActualWidth gives me 10px, which is the default width of textbox with no text. After string "Some text inside Textbox" it should be at least 110px Width.

Comment: @tjohn Running your exact code I get 15 for the actual width for the first keypress and 145 for the actual width after the second keypress. Are you saying that you get 10 _after you let the control render so the that actual width is re-calculated_?

Comment: I am saying that i get ActualWidth = 10 and Width = NaN after i run: TextBox1.Text = "Some text inside Textbox"; On second press you get the correct value, but that is too late, because i set the width first.

Comment: @tjohn - I'm trying to explain that this is because ActualWidth is a *calculated field* and therfore *it takes a while* from the second you change the Text Property until you get the correct value. I updated my answer with an example that works.

Comment: Thx for the solution, which i consider bad practice of what should have been 1 simple property, but i'll consider this as solved for now.

Answer (score -3):

Use JavaScript as it's the only way to get the correct size of the Textarea on the Client side as they could be using any browser? If you have jQuery very easy to do can also be done with native javascript.

Then get JavaScript to post that value in a Hidden input and get the value of the Input in your server based code to use where needed.

Comment: This is a WPF application. Javascript is not an option